# SQL Server command timeout: 3 options with .NET Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, command-timeout

From time to time I get a Azure database transaction timeout from a .NET core application using entity framework. What's the hierachy of setting the command timeout? There are three options: a) within the connection string, b) Options, Query execution settings, c) buidler, AddDbContext options. Since the timeout never really precisely happens at the configured timeout settings I would like to know.

Apparently just setting it with the connection string doesn't work.

This is the transaction code:

```
protected async Task UpdateDatabaseAsync() {

    Logger.LogInformation( "Updating database..." );

    // convert BlockingCollection to list
    var scrapeResults = ScrapeResultsModel.ToList();

    // check if list is empty
    if( scrapeResults.Count == 0 )
        Logger.LogInformation( "List is empty, nothing to update!" );
    else {

        // create a TransactionScope to ensure all or nothing
        // Not using "using" here for DB context/connection is recommended by MS because of DI container.
        using var transactionScope = new TransactionScope( TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled );
        try {

            // load all objects by ObjectId from _scrapeResultModel from DB
            List<string> objectIds = new();
            foreach( var result in scrapeResults ) {
                objectIds.Add( result.ObjectId );
            }
            var query = DbContext.RealEstates.Where( x => objectIds.Contains( x.ObjectId ) );
            var existingRecords = await query.ToListAsync();

            // compare lists
            for( int i = 0; i < existingRecords.Count; i++ ) {
                for( int j = scrapeResults.Count - 1; j >= 0; j-- ) {

                    // exclusions for scraped objects here

                    // remove cemetery objects
                    var title = scrapeResults[ j ].Title?.ToLower();
                    var fullText = scrapeResults[ j ].FullTextEs?.ToLower();
                    if( fullText != null && title != null &&
                        ( title.Contains( "cementerio" ) || fullText.Contains( "cementerio" ) ) ) {
                        Logger.LogInformation(
                            $"Object {scrapeResults[ j ].ObjectId} is a cemetery/cementerio, removed from list! Title: {scrapeResults[ j ].Title}" );
                        scrapeResults.RemoveAt( j );
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if objects have the same ObjectId compare prices
                    if( existingRecords[ i ].ObjectId == scrapeResults[ j ].ObjectId ) {
                        if( existingRecords[ i ].PriceTotal == scrapeResults[ j ].PriceTotal &&
                            existingRecords[ i ].RentMonthly == scrapeResults[ j ].RentMonthly ) {

                            // if object already exists and price has not changed, delete from list
                            Logger.LogInformation(
                                $"Object {scrapeResults[ j ].ObjectId} already exists, removed from list." );
                            scrapeResults.RemoveAt( j );
                        }
                        else {
                            // Mark the new price as changed.
                            // Leave the object in list and it will be added to DB.
                            // Multiple entries will be created for the same object!
                            // for sale:
                            if( scrapeResults[ j ].Type == 1 ) {
                                scrapeResults[ j ].LastChangedField += "PriceTotal,";
                                scrapeResults[ j ].DateLastChange = DateTime.UtcNow;
                                decimal.TryParse( existingRecords[ i ].PriceTotal, out var oldPrice );
                                decimal.TryParse( scrapeResults[ j ].PriceTotal, out var newPrice );
                                if( oldPrice > 0 ) {
                                    var discount = decimal.Round( ( newPrice - oldPrice ) / oldPrice * 100, 2 );
                                    scrapeResults[ j ].Discount = discount.ToString( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );
                                    Logger.LogInformation(
                                        $"New price for object {scrapeResults[ j ].ObjectId}: {scrapeResults[ j ].PriceTotal}" );

                                }
                            }
                            // for rent:
                            else if( scrapeResults[ j ].Type == 2 ) {
                                scrapeResults[ j ].LastChangedField += "RentMonthly,";
                                scrapeResults[ j ].DateLastChange = DateTime.UtcNow;
                                decimal.TryParse( existingRecords[ i ].RentMonthly, out var oldPrice );
                                decimal.TryParse( scrapeResults[ j ].RentMonthly, out var newPrice );
                                if( oldPrice > 0 ) {
                                    var discount = decimal.Round( ( oldPrice - newPrice ) / oldPrice * 100, 2 );
                                    scrapeResults[ j ].Discount = discount.ToString( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );
                                    Logger.LogInformation(
                                        $"New price for object {scrapeResults[ j ].ObjectId}: {scrapeResults[ j ].RentMonthly}" );
                                }
                            }
                            else
                                throw new Exception( "Unknown type!" );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // convert image BlockingCollection to list
            var scrapeResultsImage = ScrapeResultsImage.ToList();
            // add related images to real estate objects
            for( int i = 0; i < scrapeResults.Count; i++ ) {
                Logger.LogInformation( $"New image to DB for RealEstate objectId: {scrapeResults[ i ].ObjectId}" );
                for( int j = 0; j < scrapeResultsImage.Count; j++ ) {
                    if( scrapeResults[ i ].ObjectId == scrapeResultsImage[ j ].ObjectId ) {
                        Logger.LogInformation(
                            $"New image to DB, Guid = {scrapeResultsImage[ j ].Guid}, ObjectId = {scrapeResults[ i ].ObjectId}" );
                        scrapeResults[ i ].Images.Add( scrapeResultsImage[ j ] );
                    }
                }
            }

            // add completed list to DB
            Logger.LogInformation( $"Adding complete list with {scrapeResults.Count} items to DB..." );
            if( scrapeResults.Count > 0 ) {
                await DbContext.RealEstates.AddRangeAsync( scrapeResults );
                // Microsoft: SaveChangesAsync() is not recommended for use with TransactionScope.
                var result = DbContext.SaveChanges();
                transactionScope.Complete();
                Logger.LogInformation( $"List added to DB, commit! Results = {result}" );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            Logger.LogError( e, "Error updating database, rollback!" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a low command timeout wrapped around a slow transaction. If your transactions are exceeding your command timeouts, the problem isn't that your timeout is too short, the problem is that your transactions are too complex. Transactions should be short and sweet, not timeout-threatening.

Comment: Definitely not complex but updating one filed only. But it might be the async commit:if( scrapeResults.Count > 0 ) {
    await DbContext.RealEstates.AddRangeAsync( scrapeResults );
    // Microsoft: SaveChangesAsync() is not recommended for use with TransactionScope.
    var result = DbContext.SaveChanges();
    transactionScope.Complete();
    Logger.LogInformation( $"List added to DB, commit! Results = {result}" );
}

Comment: Nobody can read code in comments, but are you starting a transaction in SQL Server and then going and scraping some web pages inside that transaction? Don't do this. Start your transaction when you're ready to push changes to the database and, probably, don't use the application's concept of "transaction" for this at all.

Comment: No, I don't. It is a simple insert effecting two tables by EF6. I try to add the code...

Comment: Like I suspected, that seems like _a lot of stuff_ to do inside a single transaction.

Comment: FWIW If you have to add comments like `// load all objects by ObjectId from _scrapeResultModel from DB1` to me it is a code smell that you can do that (in a testable  method?) then move on to the next "thing" you need to do...and not wrap it all in ONE transaction that also does the update parts etc.

Comment: I removed the TransactionScope and made the method synchronous. After 28 seconds the (very simple) insert into a varbinary column was done at the basic level Azure SQL server DB. Since this is my first try with EF core I am not very excited because I got caught by another async issue still open after 3 years: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/593

Comment: // load all objects by ObjectId from _scrapeResultModel from DB1 -> yes, I saw that later too. Not only EF first time but also Linq. I am getting used to it though...